# I am putting the correct password in laravel but it display error password does not match|Password and cpassword fields not match

Tags: laravel, change-password

Blade code is here:

```
<div class="">
            <input class="input--style-1 text-success form-control pl-3" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Password">
            <span class="text-danger font-italic" >{{$errors->first('Password')}}</span>
          </div><br>

          <div class="">
            <input class="input--style-1 text-success form-control pl-3" type="password" placeholder="Confirm_Password" name="C_Password">
            <span class="text-danger font-italic" >{{$errors->first('C_Password')}}</span>
          </div><br>
```

DonorRequest.php code is here:

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'Name'=>'required|min:2|max:20|alpha_dash',
            'Blood_Group'=>'required',
            'Email'=>'required|Email:rfc,dns',
            'Contact'=>'required|numeric',
            'Gender'=>'required',
            'Location'=>'required',
            'Password'=>'required|min:6',
            'C_Password'=>'required|min:6|confirmed'


        ];
    }
    public function messages()
    {
        return[
            'Location.required'=>'Kindly Search And Select Location From Map'

        ];
    }
```

I am new on Laravel so i am not able to find this error. what can be problem in backend?

Answer (score 1):

Since your password input name is `Password` the name of the confirmation input must be `Password_confirmation`

So change this:

```
<div class="">
       <input class="input--style-1 text-success form-control pl-3" type="password" placeholder="Confirm_Password" name="C_Password">
       <span class="text-danger font-italic" >{{$errors->first('C_Password')}}</span>
</div><br>
```

To this:

```
<div class="">
       <input class="input--style-1 text-success form-control pl-3" type="password" placeholder="Confirm_Password" name="Password_confirmation">
       <span class="text-danger font-italic" >{{$errors->first('C_Password')}}</span>
</div><br>
```

According to @miken32 validation on the confirmation field is not needed, so you can remove this line `'C_Password'=>'required|min:6|confirmed'`.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-confirmed

Comment: No validation rule is needed for the password confirmation field, only the password field.